# VB.Net: Code to find the number of rows in a table does not work correctly

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have this function that should return 1 if the id exists and 0 if not.
When debugging I found that the query sent to sqlserver is correct and returns 1 row, also I see 1 in the ds Table count =1 but the function returns 0. 
Is there a better way to do this ? And what is the problem?

```
Public Function check_id() As Integer
    Try
        connexion = New SqlConnection(chaine_de_connexion)
        da = New SqlDataAdapter("select * from table_x where id=5", connexion)
        ds = New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "Info")
        If ds.Tables("Info").Rows.Count > 0 Then
          Return 1
        Else
          Return 0
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
       Return 0
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: you are missing an `End If`

Comment: Without the End If the code doesn't compile

Comment: i missed end if only when writing the post,i have it in the code, as saied by steve code won't compile without endif.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `check_id()` function returns a YES or NO.. so why not use a `Boolean` data type?

If you change the return type to `Boolean` you could do:

```
Return 0 < ds.Tables("Info").Rows.Count
```

Comment: This is good answer for my second question, for my first question it was because of the connexion string. 
thanks